# Compile Error: duplicate alias: Name when trying to save the apex class

Tags: apex, soql

I have 3 recordtypes for the selection in the VF page which is using the same query to fetch the records,but when user selects one of the record type, i have to group it by status field and i have to subtotal on amount fields that i have written in the query.
Before this query was a string,as i am using group by and sum function i have made it AggregateResult[] type.
I dont know where i am doing wrong.

Please guide.

```
 AggregateResult[] query =[Select Strategy__c,Deal_Currency__c,Sector__c,Fund_Size_Millions__c,Geography_New__c,Point_of_Contact_lookup__c,Point_of_Contact_lookup__r.name,Timing_Quarter__c,Timing_Year__c,Total_Leverage__c,Description__c,Source1__r.name, Term_Sheet_Provided__c, Status__c,Analyst1__r.name, Sr_Leverage__c, Sponsor__c,Sponsor__r.name, Source_Contact2__c, Source_Contact1__c, Seller__c, Revenue_mm__c, Name,Mezz_Tranche_Amount__c,EBITDA_mm__c, Deal_source__c, Date_Received__c, Banker__c, Analyst1__c,Priority__c,Timing__c, Transaction_Type__c,Deal_source__r.name,Equity_amount__c,Equity_Payment_Amount__c,Debt_Payment_Amount__c,Debt_Amount__c,Japan_Debt_Amount__c,SUM(Equity_amount__c) EquityAmount,SUM(Equity_Payment_Amount__c) EquityPayment,SUM(Debt_Payment_Amount__c) DebtPayment,SUM(Debt_Amount__c) Debt,SUM(Japan_Debt_Amount__c) lifeJapan From Log__c];

    query += whereClause;
    //query += whereClause;
    if(isMezzRecordType)
    {
    query+= ' GROUP BY Status__c';

    }

    query += ' order by Date_Received__c asc, name asc';

     List<Log__c> Logs = null; 

     Logs = Database.query(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

AggregateResult tends to catch multiple `name` in it. Just make those different by alias like below
`SELECT Point_of_Contact_lookup__r.name pclName, Source1__r.name sName, ...`

In addition to this you have extra `,` in your query (after `Description__c` field). Try to remove one and performing the query.

Comment: ,even after removing , the same error its showing

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer

Comment: i did as you said,now i am getting different error as below "Field must be grouped or aggregated: Strategy__c"